# Performance of wp_get_attachment_image_srcset() and wp_get_attachment_image_url()

Tags: query, mysql, performance, images

I like to know if this to functions being used on pageload could cause a performance problems and if it would make sense to cache the results in a transients.

`wp_get_attachment_image_url()` and `wp_get_attachment_image_srcset()` are called for multiple images at pageload.

I am curious if it would make sense to cache the results with transients. I do this for images I get from external servers but my guess would be that WP is already optimized on its own so that this would not make sense.

Comment: You mean slow for server or slow rendering in the browser? I would suggest you to profile it first, there are many plugins and tools out there that can help with that.

Comment: I mean server, mysql queries are claimed to go high with my code. I have no clue about performance testing. Telling me this plugins would be great. Still why should I test if if someone who knows WP well just can tell me how many possible database queries can this functions produce if say a couple of images are requested on a page and what WP does internally.

Comment: It's hard to say how these functions are being used in the wild or what's being hooked into them. It's e.g. not clear how many times these functions are being called and what is the "high number" of mysql calls being reported? Maybe it's just the same for everyone else using these functions? If the code produces high number of mysql queries, then one can e.g. use the [query-monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) plugin to check it out, but in general plugin/tools  recommendations are off-topic here on this site.. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, I keep that plugin in mind. I think I will just roll out some code where I cache and let the guy test it.